# linear equations; method by integrating factors

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y' -y =4te^{2t}$$ find the solution of the given initial value problem $y(0)=1 $

so basically what I found out obviously is that $exp^{\int -1dt}$ gives the integrating factor $e^{-t}$ right?

and then I multiply the whole equation with that so I get

$(y' - y)e^{-t} = 4te^{2t}  e^{-t}$

and now the struggle, I have no idea how to simplify this thing, somehow in the solution manual they somehow get $(e^{-t}y)' = 2te^t$? I mean I see how you get $e^t$ when you multiply $e^{2t} e^{-t}$ but where did that coefficient come from? thanks for any help, tips, trying to learn this stuff for once.

Comment: Improve your formatting like this using $

Comment: Can't see why it is not $4$.

Answer (score 1):

i think it may be solved using the general solution  .
Y(h) -->
$m-1=0$  --- > m=1 .
  $y = C$. ( exponential (mx) ) .
  and F(x) -->
  $Yp=A(exp(mx)$  .
  $(y)General solution = Yp + Yh$ . i wish i helped you , thats all i know .

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be having a problem with $(e^{-t}y)'$ where in fact it originally was $(y'-y)e^{-t}$

Let's try differentiating $f(y)=e^{-t}y$ with respect to $t$ using the product rule

$$f'(y)= e^{-t}\frac{dy}{dt} + y\frac{d(e^{-t})}{dt}$$

$$= e^{-t}y' + y(-e^{-t})$$

$$=e^{-t}(y'-y)$$

which is exactly what you had.

Answer (score 0):

$$
(\mathrm{e}^{-t}y)'=4t\mathrm{e}^t=\big((4t-4)\mathrm{e}^t\big)',
$$
and hence
$$
\mathrm{e}^{-t}y=(4t-4)\mathrm{e}^t+c,
$$
for some $c$ constant, and since $y(0)=1$, we obtain at $t=0$
$$
1=y(0)=-4+c,
$$
and hence $c=5$. Thus
$$
y(t)=(4t-4)\mathrm{e}^{2t}+5\,\mathrm{e}^{t}.
$$